# Spring Boot Liquibase does not recognize databasechangelog execution

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase, liquibase-maven-plugin

I'm struggling to make Spring Boot Liquibase identify the changes that are already in the database

Liquibase was added to an existent database following these steps:

1. execute a generated-changelog (to create the **databasechangelog** table based on existent tables)
2. execute a changelog-sync (where **resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-baseline.xml** described below was generated)

Below you can find all details about Spring Boot configuration and data databasechangelog table data.

The latest block shows the exception (due liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: relation "company" already exists) I'm facing trying to start the application.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test_db
    username: myapp
    password: pass12345
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        ddl-auto: none
        format_sql: true
  liquibase:
    change-log: classpath:db/db.changelog-root.xml
```

**LiquibaseLabApplication.java**

```
package com.example.liquibaselab;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class LiquibaseLabApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LiquibaseLabApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**databasechangelog**

| id | author | filename | dateexecuted | orderexecuted | exectype | md5sum | description | comments | tag | liquibase | contexts | labels | deployment_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1656504084409-1 | liquibase (generated) | db.changelog-baseline.xml | 2022-06-29 12:01:26.427877 | 1 | EXECUTED | 8:782adbb55688283f6690c848df3ff379 | createTable tableName=company |  | NULL | 4.10.0 | NULL | NULL | 6504086279.0 |
| 1656504084409-2 | liquibase (generated) | db.changelog-baseline.xml | 2022-06-29 12:01:26.435501 | 2 | EXECUTED | 8:da536519174a61bb82d743a69184a533 | createTable tableName=manager |  | NULL | 4.10.0 | NULL | NULL | 6504086279.0 |
| 1656504084409-3 | liquibase (generated) | db.changelog-baseline.xml | 2022-06-29 12:01:26.441231 | 3 | EXECUTED | 8:436718701e5c6337cd9478f0827ac301 | createTable tableName=employee |  | NULL | 4.10.0 | NULL | NULL | 6504086279.0 |
| 1656504084409-4 | liquibase (generated) | db.changelog-baseline.xml | 2022-06-29 12:01:26.446085 | 4 | EXECUTED | 8:13218bc62fcaba1f6ec7e8e9a6a663cb | addForeignKeyConstraint baseTableName=employee, constraintName=fk_manager_company_id, referencedTableName=manager |  | NULL | 4.10.0 | NULL | NULL | 6504086279.0 |
| 1656504084409-5 | liquibase (generated) | db.changelog-baseline.xml | 2022-06-29 12:01:26.451618 | 5 | EXECUTED | 8:e7d140adc1a13fca6864b12c7a7ed708 | addForeignKeyConstraint baseTableName=manager, constraintName=fk_manager_company_id, referencedTableName=company |  | NULL | 4.10.0 | NULL | NULL | 6504086279.0 |

**resources/db/db.changelog-root.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.1.xsd">

    <includeAll path="db/changelog/"/>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

**resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-baseline.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
                   xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
                   xmlns:pro="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/pro/liquibase-pro-4.6.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-4.6.xsd">
    <changeSet author="liquibase (generated)" id="1656504084409-1">
        <createTable tableName="company">
            <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="INTEGER">
                <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="company_pkey"/>
            </column>
            <column name="name" type="VARCHAR">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="liquibase (generated)" id="1656504084409-2">
        <createTable tableName="manager">
            <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="INTEGER">
                <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="manager_pkey"/>
            </column>
            <column name="full_name" type="VARCHAR">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="company_id" type="INTEGER"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="liquibase (generated)" id="1656504084409-3">
        <createTable tableName="employee">
            <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="INTEGER">
                <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="employee_pkey"/>
            </column>
            <column name="full_name" type="VARCHAR">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="manager_id" type="INTEGER"/>
        </createTable>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="liquibase (generated)" id="1656504084409-4">
        <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="manager_id" baseTableName="employee"
                                 constraintName="fk_manager_company_id" deferrable="false" initiallyDeferred="false"
                                 onDelete="NO ACTION" onUpdate="NO ACTION" referencedColumnNames="id"
                                 referencedTableName="manager" validate="true"/>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="liquibase (generated)" id="1656504084409-5">
        <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="company_id" baseTableName="manager"
                                 constraintName="fk_manager_company_id" deferrable="false" initiallyDeferred="false"
                                 onDelete="NO ACTION" onUpdate="NO ACTION" referencedColumnNames="id"
                                 referencedTableName="company" validate="true"/>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

**Exception**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.1)

2022-06-29 15:24:40.860  INFO 14000 --- [           main] o.m.l.LiquibaseLabApplication            : Starting LiquibaseLabApplication using Java 13.0.1 on dfr01-ID8B25ST7 with PID 14000 (C:\UBS\Dev\code\liquibase-lab-main\liquibase-lab-main\target\classes started by lucasmor in C:\UBS\Dev\code\liquibase-lab-main\liquibase-lab-main)
2022-06-29 15:24:40.864  INFO 14000 --- [           main] o.m.l.LiquibaseLabApplication            : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-06-29 15:24:41.792  INFO 14000 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-06-29 15:24:41.814  INFO 14000 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 10 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-06-29 15:24:42.749  INFO 14000 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-06-29 15:24:42.763  INFO 14000 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-06-29 15:24:42.763  INFO 14000 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.64]
2022-06-29 15:24:42.988  INFO 14000 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-06-29 15:24:42.988  INFO 14000 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2004 ms
2022-06-29 15:24:43.334  INFO 14000 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-06-29 15:24:43.436  INFO 14000 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-06-29 15:24:43.639  INFO 14000 --- [           main] liquibase.database                       : Set default schema name to test_app
2022-06-29 15:24:43.874  INFO 14000 --- [           main] liquibase.lockservice                    : Successfully acquired change log lock
2022-06-29 15:24:44.082  INFO 14000 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog                      : Reading resource: db/changelog/db.changelog-baseline.xml
2022-06-29 15:24:44.610  INFO 14000 --- [           main] liquibase.changelog                      : Reading from test_app.databasechangelog
Running Changeset: db/changelog/db.changelog-baseline.xml::1656504084409-1::liquibase (generated)
2022-06-29 15:24:44.835  INFO 14000 --- [           main] liquibase.lockservice                    : Successfully released change log lock
2022-06-29 15:24:44.837  WARN 14000 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set db/changelog/db.changelog-baseline.xml::1656504084409-1::liquibase (generated):
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: relation "company" already exists [Failed SQL: (0) CREATE TABLE test_app.company (id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL, name VARCHAR NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT company_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id))]
2022-06-29 15:24:44.837  INFO 14000 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-06-29 15:24:44.847  INFO 14000 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2022-06-29 15:24:44.852  INFO 14000 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-06-29 15:24:44.867  INFO 14000 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-06-29 15:24:44.896 ERROR 14000 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set db/changelog/db.changelog-baseline.xml::1656504084409-1::liquibase (generated):
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: relation "company" already exists [Failed SQL: (0) CREATE TABLE test_app.company (id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL, name VARCHAR NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT company_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id))]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.1.jar:2.7.1]
    at org.test.liquibaselab.LiquibaseLabApplication.main(LiquibaseLabApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set db/changelog/db.changelog-baseline.xml::1656504084409-1::liquibase (generated):
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: relation "company" already exists [Failed SQL: (0) CREATE TABLE test_app.company (id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL, name VARCHAR NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT company_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id))]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:126) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.lambda$null$0(Liquibase.java:265) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:180) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:189) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:179) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:158) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:243) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.lambda$update$1(Liquibase.java:264) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:180) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:189) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:179) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:158) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.runInScope(Liquibase.java:2405) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:211) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:197) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:314) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:269) ~[liquibase-core-4.9.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out the filename path was the issue:

My changelog file that was generated by **changelog-sync** was put at: *resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-baseline.xml*, but as you can see in the databasechangelog table below it was just showing the file name (filename column) with the full path to it.

| id | author | filename | dateexecuted | orderexecuted | exectype | md5sum | description | comments | tag | liquibase | contexts | labels | deployment_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1656504084409-1 | liquibase (generated) | **db.changelog-baseline.xml** | 2022-06-29 12:01:26.427877 | 1 | EXECUTED | 8:782adbb55688283f6690c848df3ff379 | createTable tableName=company |  | NULL | 4.10.0 | NULL | NULL | 6504086279.0 |
| 1656504084409-2 | liquibase (generated) | **db.changelog-baseline.xml** | 2022-06-29 12:01:26.435501 | 2 | EXECUTED | 8:da536519174a61bb82d743a69184a533 | createTable tableName=manager |  | NULL | 4.10.0 | NULL | NULL | 6504086279.0 |
| 1656504084409-3 | liquibase (generated) | **db.changelog-baseline.xml** | 2022-06-29 12:01:26.441231 | 3 | EXECUTED | 8:436718701e5c6337cd9478f0827ac301 | createTable tableName=employee |  | NULL | 4.10.0 | NULL | NULL | 6504086279.0 |
| 1656504084409-4 | liquibase (generated) | **db.changelog-baseline.xml** | 2022-06-29 12:01:26.446085 | 4 | EXECUTED | 8:13218bc62fcaba1f6ec7e8e9a6a663cb | addForeignKeyConstraint baseTableName=employee, constraintName=fk_manager_company_id, referencedTableName=manager |  | NULL | 4.10.0 | NULL | NULL | 6504086279.0 |
| 1656504084409-5 | liquibase (generated) | **db.changelog-baseline.xml** | 2022-06-29 12:01:26.451618 | 5 | EXECUTED | 8:e7d140adc1a13fca6864b12c7a7ed708 | addForeignKeyConstraint baseTableName=manager, constraintName=fk_manager_company_id, referencedTableName=company |  | NULL | 4.10.0 | NULL | NULL | 6504086279.0 |

Updating the table like below solved the issue and Spring Boot started and verified Liquibase logs successfully.

| id | author | filename | dateexecuted | orderexecuted | exectype | md5sum | description | comments | tag | liquibase | contexts | labels | deployment_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1656504084409-1 | liquibase (generated) | **db/changelog/db.changelog-baseline.xml** | 2022-06-29 12:01:26.427877 | 1 | EXECUTED | 8:782adbb55688283f6690c848df3ff379 | createTable tableName=company |  | NULL | 4.10.0 | NULL | NULL | 6504086279.0 |
| 1656504084409-2 | liquibase (generated) | **db/changelog/db.changelog-baseline.xml** | 2022-06-29 12:01:26.435501 | 2 | EXECUTED | 8:da536519174a61bb82d743a69184a533 | createTable tableName=manager |  | NULL | 4.10.0 | NULL | NULL | 6504086279.0 |
| 1656504084409-3 | liquibase (generated) | **db/changelog/db.changelog-baseline.xml** | 2022-06-29 12:01:26.441231 | 3 | EXECUTED | 8:436718701e5c6337cd9478f0827ac301 | createTable tableName=employee |  | NULL | 4.10.0 | NULL | NULL | 6504086279.0 |
| 1656504084409-4 | liquibase (generated) | **db/changelog/db.changelog-baseline.xml** | 2022-06-29 12:01:26.446085 | 4 | EXECUTED | 8:13218bc62fcaba1f6ec7e8e9a6a663cb | addForeignKeyConstraint baseTableName=employee, constraintName=fk_manager_company_id, referencedTableName=manager |  | NULL | 4.10.0 | NULL | NULL | 6504086279.0 |
| 1656504084409-5 | liquibase (generated) | **db/changelog/db.changelog-baseline.xml** | 2022-06-29 12:01:26.451618 | 5 | EXECUTED | 8:e7d140adc1a13fca6864b12c7a7ed708 | addForeignKeyConstraint baseTableName=manager, constraintName=fk_manager_company_id, referencedTableName=company |  | NULL | 4.10.0 | NULL | NULL | 6504086279.0 |

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when executing your xml changeset against your DB the table `company` already exists. So when it executes `<createTable>` liquibase will fail. In SQL-based changesets this can be easily avoided using the keywords "IF NOT EXISTS"

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_app.company (id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL, name VARCHAR NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT company_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id))
```

However, in xml-based changesets the only way to avoid this would probably be by using liquibase `preconditions` before your `<createTable>` statements.

```
<preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
  <not>
    <tableExists tableName="company"/>
  </not>
</preConditions>
```

I would recommend reviewing these [precondition](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/preconditions.html) docs for more info on liquibase preconditions & also the [create-table](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/create-table.html) docs as well.

Comment: If I have to control when, for example, tables exist, what is the point to use Liquibase?